# Классы c#. Как создать поле список

Tags: c#, классы

как создать поле в классе на c#,чтобы этим полем был список?
вот пример.

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stack
{
    class ListStack<T>
    {
        private LinkedList<T> kr = new LinkedList<T>();
        public LinkedList<T> KR
        {
            get
            {
                return kr;
            }
        }
        kr.
    }
}
```

я создал поле,но я не могу обращаться к kr. Почему?

Comment: вот это `kr.` не находится ни в геттере, ни в сеттере, ни в методе, ни в конструкторе. Оно написано там, где его быть не должно, потому и не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы объявили член класса, но не создали объект, на который этот член класса должен ссылаться:

```
private LinkedList kr = new LinkedList();
public LinkedList KR { get { return kr; } } // если надо
```

Строчка

```
kr.
```

не может находится просто в теле класса, висеть в воздухе. Вы, очевидно, намеревались поместить ее в какой-то метод.

```
public int GetCount()
{
   return kr.Count;
}
```

Comment: неверно всё равно. я написал без второй строчки. Можете пояснить,пожалуйста, её суть?

Comment: @Артём Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Доверьтесь мне. Код - верный.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public

Comment: написал полностью также,но не работает

Comment: "но не работает" - маленький гномик вылез из компьютера и сказал: "Не работает."?

Comment: @Артём покажите полностью весь ваш код, что вы написали. Вы определение класса не забыли? Какая ошибка?

Comment: нет,суть в том,что просто не видит моего объекта. выдаётся сообщение,что данного имени не существует в текущем контексте,сейчас покажу

Comment: @Igor теперь хочу компьютер с гномиком, что делать? :D

Comment: @Артём Вы считаете, я способен вообразить Ваш контекст, не видя Вашего экрана?  Вы мне льстите. Спасибо.

Comment: вот выложил полный код. немного не понял ваш вопрос? мне нужен список для работы в моём классе,но я не могу к нему обращаться

Comment: @tym32167 Сейчас, еще немного, и Артём сообразит, чего не хватает в его вопросе.

Comment: К сожалению,так и не могу понять почему нельзя обратиться?

Comment: благодарю. невнимательность моя